# How to interpret the figure produced by "visualgc" for G1 garbage collector?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvisualvm, g1gc

I am trying to tune G1 GC in my application (using Java 1.8.0_66; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM), by utilizing the `visualgc` plugin of `jvisualvm` (also in version of 1.8.0_66).

However, I failed to read any information related to G1 from the profiling figure below.

[image: visualgc for g1]

> How to interpret the figure in terms of G1?

Comment: gclog will provide more info. Did you check that file too?

Comment: @ravindra Not yet. I will. It seems that `visualgc` does not support G1 gc.

Comment: what kind of information are you looking for? i mean there has to be a reason why you're looking at it in the first place. graphs can be analyzed for many different details. surely you don't expect an exhaustive enumeration of all possibilities. also, as @ravindra says, GC logs (`-XX:+PrintGCDetails`) are generally more useful.